# Groupoidification of infinity categories and geometric realization

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Suppose we have an $(\infty,1)$-category $\mathcal{C}$. There are two ways I can think of to produce an $(\infty,0)$-category from $\mathcal{C}$, and I'm wondering if they're equivalent.

The first way is as follows. Let $\operatorname{Cat}$ be the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories, and let $\operatorname{Grpd}$ be the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-groupoids. There is a forgetful functor $F: \operatorname{Grpd} \to \operatorname{Cat}$ which admits a left adjoint $Str: \operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Grpd}$, which one could call the "groupoidification functor". Roughly, $Str(\mathcal{C})$ inverts all the arrows in $\mathcal{C}$.

The second method starts by viewing $\mathcal{C}$ as a category object in the infinity category $\operatorname{Grpd}$. More precisely, there is a fully faithful functor $s: \operatorname{Cat} \to Fun(\Delta^{op},\operatorname{Grpd})$, which assigns to $\mathcal{C}$ the simplicial object
$$s \mathcal{C}: \Delta^{op} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Grpd}$$
whose space of zero simplices is the core of $\mathcal{C}$, its $1$-simplices is the space of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, and so on. By taking the geometric realization of $s\mathcal{C}$ we get an $\infty$-groupoid $|s\mathcal{C}|$.

Question: Is the composition $|-| \circ s$ equivalent to the groupoidification functor? This seems intuitively obvious to me; e.g. two $0$-simplices of $s\mathcal{C}$ are identified in $|s\mathcal{C}|$ whenever they're joined by a $1$-simplex.

EDIT: I replaced all instances of "strictification" with "groupoidification," in order to avoid any confusion for future readers.

Comment: Just a note that this should not be called "strictification", but rather something like "localization" or "groupoidification" (although the latter also has other meanings).

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks! What is the usual meaning of "strictification," if any?

Comment: Another common name for $Str(C)$ is "weak homotopy type of $C$" (although I don't know if that can be adapted to a name for the functor $Str$...)

Comment: A "strict higher category" is one whose higher coherences hold not just up to (coherent) isomorphism, but actually up to equality. For example, a "strict 2-category" is a bicategory where the associativity and unitality hold strictly. The 2-category of categories and functors is a strict 2-category. The 2-category of algebras and bimodules, for example, is not a strict 2-category — the composition of bimodules is a tensor product, and if you define it as, say, some sort of quotient of a space spanned by ordered pairs, then this will not be strictly associative — but it is obviously equivalent

Comment: to a sub-2-category of the strict 2-category of categories (namely: to an algebra, assign its category of modules, and to a bimodule, assign the functor that tensors with that bimodule).

Comment: Given this use of the word "strict", the term "strictification" is generally used to mean a procedure which replaces your not-necessarily-strict higher category by a strict one.

Comment: An example is a result of Mac Lane that every bicategory, and in particular every monoidal 1-category (these being the bicategories on one object), is equivalent to a strict one, and so you can "strictify" any bicategory.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Thanks for elaborating on this, as well as the examples. The abbreviation "str" appeared in a text I was reading, so I assumed it meant "strict". Now to choose a new name...

Comment: I think it might stand for be "straightening", but I could be misremembering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, and this is why people sometimes use $|C|$ to denote $Str(C)$.

Consider the following composite $Fun(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd}) \to Fun^{cpl, Segal}(\Delta^{op}, \mathrm{Grpd}) \to Cat_\infty \to \mathrm{Grpd}$ where the first map is the left adjoint to the inclusion of complete Segal spaces, the second is the equivalence between complete Segal spaces and $\infty$-categories, and the last one is $Str$.

I claim that this map is given by geometric realization, i.e. $\mathrm{colim}_{\Delta^{op}}$. For this, because all the maps appearing are left adjoints, it suffices to show that the composite of right adjoints is equivalent to the constant functor.

But the string of right adjoints sends an $\infty$-groupoid $X$ to the $[n]\mapsto map([n],X)$, which is constant equivalent to $X$ - indeed, because $|\Delta^{op}|$ is contractible, to show that a simplicial groupoid is constant it suffices to show that it sends all maps $[0]\to [n]$ in $\Delta^{op}$ to equivalences, but $map([0],X)\to map([n],X)$ is an equivalence, as the map of $\infty$-categories $[n]\to [0]$ induces an equivalence $Str([n])\to Str([0])$.

In particular this shows that the equivalence $map([\bullet ], X)\simeq X$ is natural in $X$ as well, as it is induced by a natural transformation in $\Delta^{op}$.

It follows that if you precompose it with the inclusion $Fun^{cpl,Segal}(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd})\to Fun(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd})$, you get exactly $\mathrm{colim}_{\Delta^{op}}$ , but because the composite $Fun^{cpl,Segal}(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd})\to Fun(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd})\to Fun^{cpl, Segal}(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Grpd})$ is equivalent to the identity, this composite is also equivalent to $Str$, which proves the claim.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer! What exactly is the left adjoint to the inclusion of complete Segal spaces?

Comment: Mhm I don't think there is a nice description except for "it's the left adjoint" :D (so like, you enforce Segality universally, and then completeness). It seems like a description would give descriptions for things that are known to be hard, but maybe I'm missing something - if someone knows a description I'd be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: I think that's a good enough description for now! It's enough for the proof anyway

Comment: @leibnewtz There is a formula for the left adjoint, but it's arguably not much better than just saying "the left adjoint": it sends $X$ to $\int^{[n]\in\Delta^{op}}X([n])\times [n]$ where the coend is computed in $\operatorname{Cat}_\infty$.